# Declare a variable in ViewDidLoad and use elsewhere (Swift)

Tags: swift

First Swift project, and I'm confused as to how scope works.  I'm trying to choose a random integer in ViewDidLoad and then allow the user to guess the number, but I can't work out how to access the variable `answer` created in ViewDidLoad in my button action.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var guess: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var result: UILabel!

    @IBAction func guessButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var userGuess = guess.text.toInt()
        if userGuess != nil {
            if userGuess == answer {
                result.text = "You got it!"
            } else if userGuess > answer {
                result.text = "Too high! Guess again!"
            } else {
                result.text = "Too low!  Guess again!"
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var answer = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1

        }
   }
```

Comment: Just make `answer` a variable stored property (a.k.a. "ivar").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three scopes:

- File top level
- Object type declaration top level (like your `guess`)
- Local (inside function curly braces) (like your `userGuess`)

You can only see *up* (higher surrounding scope).

So, code in `guessButton` method cannot see variable declared in `viewDidLoad` method. But they can *both* see variable declared at file top level or variable declared at object type declaration top level. Which one do you think is most appropriate here?

Comment: OK, so I guess I should declare it at the top of the file.  Does that mean it's impossible to work with a variable declared in one method in another?  That seems like a frequent use-case.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, you had a fifty-fifty chance and you got it wrong. :) Top of the file would be _too_ visible - all the code _in your whole app_ would be able to see that.

Comment: Ah, wait.  So if they can both see it, either can modify it.  Correct?

Comment: Sure, that's what "see" means. You can't refer to something you can't see. If you can see something you can refer to it. That is what scope is.

Comment: Ok, got it working (thanks) but coming from a Python background, this seems suspiciously like a global variable.  Am I wrong, or are they just not as scandalous as they are in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? Do you think your `guess` is a global variable?

Comment: No, the answer itself.  Although I guess it's just in the class itself so, no.  But had I declared it at the top of the file, it would have been, which is why that was a bad idea.  Correct?

Comment: Correct. File top level is global by default. (It is certainly global to the file.) - But I am a little worried that you are also not grasping the difference between class and instance, which for someone who claims to come from Python is a bit scary...

Comment: It's more exhaustion and carelessness than a lack of understanding.